# Redshift - user "xyz" cannot be dropped because the user owns some object

Tags: amazon-redshift

When trying to drop a user "xyz" in a Redshift database, I get the error message:

> user 'xyz' cannot be dropped because the user owns some object.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DROP_USER.html):

> If a user owns an object, first drop the object or change its ownership to another user before dropping the original user

How do I know which objects (schemas, tables, views, UDFs?, ...) are owned by the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the tables and views owned by a specific user in **pg_tables**
and **pg_views** system tables.

(There is also **pg_udf**, but it doesn't hold any reference to specific user.)

```
select 
    case when schemaname='public' then '' 
        else schemaname+'.' end+tablename 
    from pg_tables where tableowner = 'xyz'
union 
    select 
    case when schemaname='public' then ''
        else schemaname+'.' end+viewname 
    from pg_views where viewowner = 'xyz';
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the user didn't own any tables or views or anything else that I could find. I guessed correctly that having been granted a privilege meant the user "owned" something, because I fixed the problem with this:

```
revoke all privileges on database some_database_name from some_user_name
```

after which the `drop user` command worked.

Answer (score 4):

Since the following resolved the problem in so spectacularly easy fashion for me, I duplicate this response into this thread as well:

After trying suggestions from countless posts and threads, awslabs' **[aws-redshift-utils](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils)** provided relief in the form of [admin.v_find_dropuser_objs](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_find_dropuser_objs.sql) view. It instantly identified the remaining dependencies making it possible to drop the user in question.

Answer (score 0):

The following blog post by AWS explains very clearly how to resolve this issue:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-user-cannot-be-dropped/

Their script `v_find_dropuser_objs.sql` [link here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_find_dropuser_objs.sql) returns a nice table of object type, object owner, user id, schema name, object name, ddl etc.